# Trouble aligning images and making them same size HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML and CSS and am running into images misalignment and trying to make them the same size. How can I fix this?

This is the current HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center">    
  <h3>Find Your University</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
      <div id="cities">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/100644443/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="London">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://www.gaiasg.com/img/si1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Singapore">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/Argentina-8-smalltabletRetina.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://www.travelstart.com.ng/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Lagos.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="https://www.sohohousechicago.com/system/files/082014/53e8a9c2f9426120f600002e/xlarge/063696_002.jpg?1424778295" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com/dealsImages/landingPages/destinationLandingPages/other/Sydney-345x225.1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#cities .col-md-3 {
 height:570px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use another row for each 3 images:

```
    <div class="container text-center">    
  <h3>Find Your University</h3><br>

      <div id="cities">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://media.timeout.com/images/100644443/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="London">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://www.gaiasg.com/img/si1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Singapore">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/Argentina-8-smalltabletRetina.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div> </div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://www.travelstart.com.ng/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Lagos.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="https://www.sohohousechicago.com/system/files/082014/53e8a9c2f9426120f600002e/xlarge/063696_002.jpg?1424778295" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com/dealsImages/landingPages/destinationLandingPages/other/Sydney-345x225.1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on each row you can add divisions equal to 12, so col-sm-4 can be used 3 times in one row, the more cols you add the more rows you add too.

Comment: Thanks, however the images are still not aligning properly. Is my CSS correct? #cities .col-md-3 {
 height:570px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: @xtjnrchris actually there's nothing wrong, all you need to do is to use multiple rows as i mentioned, here's how it looks: http://codepen.io/mohamadfala/pen/MyGxGE
if you need the images the same height, try to crop them :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need a div for every image. Enough to have one main container for them. Try to set 2 different classes, on one of them use float:left and on the other float:right , that way they will be in the same line.
Try looking at this page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp "image floating" and test it out to understand how it works.